# How can a paramater have a value in a python function when I havn't entered a value when calling the function?

Tags: python, function, oop, kivy

I'm following along a kivy tutorial and not really understanding what I'm doing.

I don't perticulary have a problem but I just don't understand why my code works.

I call a function without giving a value for one of the paramaters and yet that paramater still displays a value???

```py
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
  super(MainWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
  self.init_vertical_lines()
  self.init_horizontal_lines()
  Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1/60)

def update(self,dt):
  time_factor = dt
  print(str(time_factor))
  self.update_vertical_lines()
  self.update_horizontal_lines()
  self.current_offset_y += self.SPEED*time_factor
```

When I run the code the time_factor is around 0.117.
How do I even get values when I never entered any value for 'dt'?

Comment: This code is not reproducible. Provide [`Minimal Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you don't pass any value to your class's update() function you'll get a TypeError exception when Python parses the source code. If *print(str(time_factor))* is emitting anything then you **must** be passing a value

Comment: Your code doesn't directly call the function: it passes the function to Kivy's `Clock.schedule_interval`, which must in turn be supplying a value for `dt` when it calls the function. Btw, are you sure that time_factor is 0.117 rather than around 0.0167 (1/60) ?